# Remove kendo Area chart padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui

There is some default padding in areachart.

I tried my best to force it make 0 padding, but no luck. 

 Any idea how areachart touches the edges of the box
 ( base css framework is bootstrap3 ).

[image]

after using ( as @suraj suggestion in comments ) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the padding inside the chart initialization. Something like this:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
   //....
  chartArea: {
    margin: 0,
    padding:0
  },
  plotArea: { margin: 0, padding:0 }
});
```

Comment: yes suraj, I tried this, its fixed only on right hand side,left side keep margin/padding gap.

added the updated images above.

Comment: Can you help with a Dojo/JsBin which will give a clearer picture?

Comment: In the meantime can u try if padding of 0 in plotArea helps? Have updated my answer with the change

Comment: plotArea = 0, no luck :'(

Comment: Can you create a sample code in a Dojo. Its difficult to make out this ways

Comment: figured it out. valueAxis:{visible:false} and categoryAxis{visible:false,}